# What does a blue empty cell mean [ ] in Anaconda if the cell above is still [*]?

Tags: jupyter, anaconda

I've been running a machine learning algorithm for two days now, I have a large dataset and a slow machine.

I noticed today that the cell below the "fit model" cell turned from green to blue, however, the cell above (the one with fit) is still running [*]

[image]

Comment: Could you add the images of the cell for better clarity?

Comment: @Soumya Done, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: This is not for anaconda rather for jupyter notebooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell with **[*]** means it is currently running, you can queue other cells for execution but until this cell finishes they will not run.

When it is empty **[]** it means you haven't run this cell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had queued up the second cell to run, I think I have seen this when the kernel crashes. Try opening another terminal and checking htop to see if it is still running.